# Pandas join: Does not recognize joining column

Tags: python, join, pandas, inner-join

I have no idea what's happening, the title is just a first-order approximation. I'm trying to join two data frames:

```
>>> df_sum.head()
         TUCASEID  t070101  t070102  t070103  t070104  t070105  t070199  \
0  20030100013280        0        0        0        0        0        0   
1  20030100013344        0        0        0        0        0        0   
2  20030100013352       60        0        0        0        0        0   
3  20030100013848        0        0        0        0        0        0   
4  20030100014165        0        0        0        0        0        0   

   t070201  t070299  shopping  year  
0        0        0         0  2003  
1        0        0         0  2003  
2        0        0        60  2003  
3        0        0         0  2003  
4        0        0         0  2003  
>>> emp.head()
         TUCASEID status
0  20030100013280    emp
1  20030100013344    emp
2  20030100013352    emp
4  20030100014165    emp
5  20030100014169    emp
```

That's the data frames, I want to join them over the common column `TUCASEID`, of which there are intersections:

```
>>> np.intersect1d(emp.TUCASEID, df_sum.TUCASEID)
array([20030100013280, 20030100013344, 20030100013352, ..., 20131212132462,
       20131212132469, 20131212132475])
```

Now...

```
>>> df_sum.join(emp, on='TUCASEID', how='inner')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3829, in join
    rsuffix=rsuffix, sort=sort)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3843, in _join_compat
    suffixes=(lsuffix, rsuffix), sort=sort)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 39, in merge
    return op.get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 193, in get_result
    rdata.items, rsuf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3873, in items_overlap_with_suffix
    to_rename)
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index([u'TUCASEID'], dtype='object')
```

Well, that's weird, the only column that appears in both data frames is the one to join over, but well, let's concur[1]:

```
>>> df_sum.join(emp, on='TUCASEID', how='inner', rsuffix='r')
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [TUCASEID, t070101, t070102, t070103, t070104, t070105, t070199, t070201, t070299, shopping, year, TUCASEIDr, status]
Index: []
```

Despite there being a huge intersection. What's going on here?

```
>>> pd.__version__
'0.15.0'
```

[1]: I actually enforced integer for dtype of the joining column because it said "object" there, made no difference:

```
>>> emp.dtypes
TUCASEID     int64
status      object
dtype: object
>>> df_sum.dtypes
TUCASEID    int64
(...)
shopping    int64
year        int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Your index values don't match why not just merge them `df_sum.merge(emp, on='TUCASEID', how='outer')` or you just interested in adding the 'status' column for each 'TUCASEID' row? in which case do `df_sum['status'] = df['sum['TUCASEID'].map(emp.set_index('TUCASEID')`

Comment: @EdChum Alright, Ill look into the alternatives. Why is it relevant that the index values don't match? I've specified the alternative `on=` column.

Comment: Dunno but `join` joins on index usually, it is strange the behaviour which I can recreate but the other methods I suggested should work

Comment: @EdChum You had typos in the last command there, I guessed `df_sum['TUCASEID'].map(emp.set_index('TUCASEID'))` and got `TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable`

Comment: Sorry try: `df_sum['status'] = df_sum.TUCASEID.map(emp.set_index('TUCASEID')['status'])`, incidently `df_sum.join(emp, on='TUCASEID', how='outer', rsuffix='r')` works but I don't know if that is what you want

Answer (score 2):

`df.join` generally calls `pd.merge` (except in a special case when it calls `concat`). Therefore, anything `join` can do, `merge` can do
also.  Although perhaps not strictly correct, I tend to use `df.join` only when
joining on the index and use `pd.merge` for joining on columns.

Thus, I can reproduce the problem you describe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_sum = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6*2).reshape((6,2)), 
                      index=list('ABCDEF'), columns=list('XY'))
emp =  pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6*2).reshape((6,2)), 
                    index=list('ABCDEF'), columns=list('XZ'))
print(df_sum.join(emp, on='X', rsuffix='_r', how='inner'))

# Empty DataFrame
# Columns: [X, Y, X_r, Z]
# Index: []
```

but `pd.merge` works as expected -- and without having to supply `rsuffix`:

```
print(pd.merge(df_sum, emp, on='X')
```

yields

```
    X   Y   Z
0   0   1   1
1   2   3   3
2   4   5   5
3   6   7   7
4   8   9   9
5  10  11  11
```

---

[Under the hood](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L3909), `df_sum.join` calls merge this way:

```
    if isinstance(other, DataFrame):
        return merge(self, other, left_on=on, how=how,
                     left_index=on is None, right_index=True,
                     suffixes=(lsuffix, rsuffix), sort=sort)
```

So, even though you use `df_sum.join(emp, on='...')`, under the hood, Pandas converts this to `pd.merge(df_sum, emp, left_on='...')`.
Furthermore, the merge is empty when called this way:

```
In [228]: pd.merge(df_sum, emp, left_on='X', left_index=False, right_index=True)
Out[228]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [X, X_x, Y, X_y, Z]
Index: []
```

because the `left_on='X'` needs to be `on='X'` for the merge to succeed as desired:

```
In [233]: pd.merge(df_sum, emp, on='X', left_index=False, right_index=True)
Out[233]: 
    X   Y   Z
A   0   1   1
B   2   3   3
C   4   5   5
D   6   7   7
E   8   9   9
F  10  11  11
```